# Excel VBA: Create Dynamic data validation formula

Tags: excel, vba

I have a below  formula which validates for IP address in Excel cell and works fine.

```
Dim cellAddress as Variant 

cellAddress =Target.value 'Target is a Range

=AND(COUNT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[.*1>-1][.*1<256]"))=4,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""))=3)
```

My problem is that I want to pass the cellAddress as a  Dynamic value to my formula instead of 'A1'

Can somebody guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `Public Function` that returns a `Boolean`, and pass in the cell reference as a `Range` to the function.

Here's an example of the code:

```vb
Option Explicit

' =AND(COUNT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[.*1>-1][.*1<256]"))=4,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""))=3)

Public Function ValidateIPAddress(source As Range) As Boolean
    ' Get the first condition's value...
    Dim xmltxt As String
    xmltxt = "<t><s>" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(source.Value, ".", "</s><s>") & "</s></t>"

    Dim sections As Variant
    sections = Application.WorksheetFunction.FilterXML(xmltxt, "//s[.*1>-1][.*1<256]")
    
    ' Get the second condition's value...
    Dim separators As Integer
    separators = Len(Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(source.Value, ".", ""))

    ' Compare both conditions and return the result
    ValidateIPAddress = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(sections) = 4 And Len(source.Value) - separators = 3
End Function
```

And here's a snippet of the usage:

[image]

I tried to break out the formula you provided to make it legible without spending too much time on it. It can definitely be improved or you can even nest everything into one line if you wanted to, but I wouldn't recommend that because it'll be difficult to debug.

---

EDIT:

If you just wanted to replace the `"A1"` string you can concatenate the `cellAddress` variable with parts of the formula.

Here's a code snippet example:

```vb
Dim validationFormula As String
validationFormula = "=AND(COUNT(FILTERXML(""<t><s>""&SUBSTITUTE(" & _
    Target.Value & ",""."",""</s><s>"")&""</s></t>"",""//s[.*1>-1][.*1<256]""))=4,LEN(" & _
    Target.Value & ")-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(" & _
    Target.Value & ",""."",""""))=3)"
    
Debug.Print validationFormula
```

Output of the formula when changing a cell's value to `"A5"`:

[image: Code Snippet Example]

Note: You have to replace all double quotes with 2 double quotes when handling quotes in strings.

Comment: Hello @brxndxn, Thanks for your time... What I was trying is that I am adding a validation to cell on worksheet change event using below... With selection.validation  .Delete. add Type and so on.... In the Formula1 region I want to apply the dynamic formula where 'A1' will get replaced to cellAddress

Comment: @Shaktiman I think I understand what your end goal is with the function and I'm certain I can help you, but I'm not unsure how you're handling it without more information. I'm assuming Target.Value is a cell address like A3 or C5 since you're setting the cell address variable to the value and not it's address.

Comment: @Shaktiman You can also concatenate strings with ampersands (&), like this: "Hello" & " " & "World" (would be "Hello World"), so you can replace the "A1" text with the variable or the target's value directly, like this: "=AND(COUNT(FILTERXML(""<t><s>""&SUBSTITUTE(" & Target.Value & ",""."",""</s><s>"")&""</s></t>"",""//s[.*1>-1][.*1<256]""))=4,LEN(" & Target.Value & ")-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(" & Target.Value & ",""."",""""))=3)"